# Send Data to specific controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm wondering if there is a good practice solution for the following situation in AngularJs:

I have a html that is basically displaying a list of elements and a controller that is the view-model and handles certain events for that list. 
I use this html/controller combination on different spots within my app by
using ng-include.

**List.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="listController">
<!--... display List here-->
</div>
```

Now I have been using events from the parent scope to fill the list controller with elements.

**ListController.js**

```
angular.module("app").controller('listController', function($scope) {
  let $scope.elements = []; 
  $scope.$on('setElementsEvent', function(event, data) {
    $scope.elements = data; 
  });
});
```

This has been working fine so far. But now I have the situation, that one parent controller has multiple of these Lists as children, but I want them to display distinct elements. With broadcasting events I would always set the elements for all child lists! Using a factory would pose the same problem, since all of the listControllers have the same controller function.

**parent.html**

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
  <!--first list-->
  <div ng-include='"List.html"'></div>

  <!-- second list -->
  <div ng-include='"List.html"'></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get this done without having to write a new controller for every list I want to display?

Comment: Good practice is not to use standalone controllers at all. Use [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice is not to use standalone controllers at all. Use [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), they accept arguments in the form of bindings.

Here you have an example usage:

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .run($rootScope => {
    $rootScope.productSetA = [{
        name: 'Foo'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bar'
      },
      {
        name: 'Baz'
      }
    ];

    $rootScope.productSetB = [{
        name: 'Fiz'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fooz'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fez'
      }
    ];

    $rootScope.productSetC = [{
        name: 'Booze'
      },
      {
        name: 'Beeze'
      },
      {
        name: 'Beep'
      }
    ];
  })
  .component('productList', {
    bindings: {products: '<'},
    template: '<div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.products" ng-bind="product.name">'
  });
```

```css
product-list {
  display: block;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='exampleApp'>
  <product-list products='productSetA'></product-list>
  <product-list products='productSetB'></product-list>
  <product-list products='productSetC'></product-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. Started digging into components, this really opens up a whole new world!

Answer (score 1):

Best way it switch to components and set attributes or require parent controller in the child.

However if you want to go with ng-include, try `ng-repeat`. It creates independent scope for every iteration and set `$index` and variable value which are available to the child scope through $scope.$parent

so your code will look like:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
    <div ng-repeat="ctrlId in ['first', 'second']" ng-include='"List.html"'></div>
</div>
```

Better way is to convert your template to components https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Answer (score 0):

well one solution in my head is to set a determinant parameter for each controller, the other solution is to use a directive for each list, you can know more about directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) , and for the first solution here's an example

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="listController" ng-init="ctrlNo=1"><!--here you set the determinant factor for this controller-->
 <!--... display List here-->
</div>
```

ListController.js

```
angular.module("app").controller('listController', function($scope) {
  $scope.ctrlNo=0;
  let $scope.elements = []; 
  $scope.$on('setElementsEvent', function(event, data) {
   if($scope.ctrlNo===1){//Here you stop the propagation to do the specific actions for the specific controller
       $scope.elements = data; 
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: all `<div ng-controller="listController" ng-init="ctrlNo=1">` are on the same scope, so all controllers will receive the same value.